# Though I did optional binding, I got error “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: swift, binding, option-type

I received data from my application server, and then assign that data to ios's object(articles).

And using that object(articles), I save values to cell's label in tableView.

After that, when user click the cell of tableView, this app move to another ViewController(NoticeArticleVC). Before moving, I assign value of object(articles) to that ViewController's variable like below code.

[image]

However, as usual, I did optional binding using 'if let' statement. But I got error as if I didn't do optional binding.

Though I cleaned build folder, and then rebuilded, it didn't work.

Please let me know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: are you sure the `titleLabel` is not `nil`? If it is an outlet, check if the outlet is connected from the storyboard.

Comment: Already I checked it. Of course it is not nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've instantiated the new ViewController, but I don't think titleLabel will be set until the view has loaded. You will need to present the new view controller and then set the label. Or better, set a variable on the new ViewController and only set the label field from within that VC code (e.g. in/after viewDidLoad).

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Following your answer, I declare new variable in new ViewController, and when it is loaded, I set value to label.

Comment: @KazakaNelson _"are you sure `titleLabel` is not `nil`?"_ _"Already I checked it. Of course it is not nil"_ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri, You said "check if the outlet is connected from the storyboard". It is well connected in storyboard. It is different problem from what you said. But thank you for commenting.